# Appache service cannot start using Laragon

Tags: server, laragon

I updated my Windows version and after that the Appache service is not start as it is attached.
[image: image of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Laragon with a newer version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).